# I can just change a switch of many

Tags: android

I'm making my first app in Android. I'm using a ArrayAdapter class to show a list of sensors and their state with a switch but I don't know why I can just set text to one switch ! The others don't change, but I can change the TextView.

The error:

```
a:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

THis is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descripcion"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- >TextView
            android:id="@+id/descripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" /-->
        <Switch
        android:id="@+id/monitored_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />

    </TableRow>
        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/urli"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And this is my ArrayAdapter class:

```
    class ListaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

    ListaAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlist,data);
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist, parent, false);
        }

        try {
//      TextView name_lbl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
//      name_lbl.setText(data.get(position).getString("name"));

        TextView desc_lbl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        desc_lbl.setText(data.get(position).getString("description"));
        Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.monitored_switch);
//        s.setChecked(true);
        s.setText("fdsdf"+data.get(position).getString("id"));
        if (s != null) {
//            s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
//      TextView url_lbl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.urli);
//      url_lbl.setText(data.get(position).getString("url"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(ListaAdapter.class.getName(),data.get(position)+"Fallo al rellenar la lista:" + e.toString());
        }

        return (row);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you forget to call `findViewById` on `row`. Try to use: `row.findViewById(R.id.monitored_switch);`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I feel so stupid! Thank you very much @vzoha